# sencha touch with phonegap (using sencha cmd and phonegap build) causes Error : LocalFileSystem not defined

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-build, sencha-cmd

I followed these sencha cmd guide to produce a phoneGap based sencha touch 2 project:
Using Latest Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67 , Latest sencha touch 2.3.1 , phoneGap ver- 3.1.0

**1)** Make a sencha touch 2 project by :

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/sencha-touch-sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/www/myapp
```

**2)** Add phoneGap to the above project

```
sencha phonegap init
```

**3)** configure the phonegap.local.properties

```
phonegap.platform=android
phonegap.build.remote=true
phonegap.build.remote.username=myUseName
phonegap.build.remote.password=myPassword
```

**4)** Updated the config.xml by adding all the core plugins

```
<!-- Core plugins -->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
```

and removed the `<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>` permission config

**5)** Created a external js file named dirReader.js and included its path in app.json

**dirReader.js Contents**

```
window.onerror=function(msg, url, linenumber){
     alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber)
     return true
    }

var dirList = [{name: 'Chart 1'},{name: 'Chart 2'}];
 // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("device ready");
            Ext.device.FileSystem.requestFileSystem(
                LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {   // LocalFileSystem not defined error here
                alert("Root = " + fs.root.fullPath);
                var directoryReader = fs.root.createReader();
                directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    //alert(entries[i].name);
                    var itemObj = {};
                        itemObj.name = entries[i].name;
                    dirList.push(itemObj);
                }
                var dirListString = JSON.stringify(dirList);
                alert(dirListString);
                }, function (error) {
                alert(error.code);
                })
                }, function (error) {
                alert(error.code);
            });
    }
```

**6)** Added `'Ext.device.FileSystem'` in requires under app.js

**7)** Finally ran `sencha app build native`
    This causes many mumbo jumbo to take place in the command prompt (No Errors) . the app is compressed and uploaded to build.phonegap for android build. Build succeeds.

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**PROBLEM**

The app installs and starts fine.
I receive the "Device Ready" alert from the dirReader.js file.
The next error I get is that `LocalFileSystem is undefined` in dirReader.js.

I tried lots of things but nothing works.

I checked that the built apk contains the plugins folder with all the plugins including the `org.apache.cordova.file` . Also , the cordova_plugins.js is present and has the `window.LocalFileSystem` entry.

Answer (score 2):

I saw somewhere the same issue.. is the cordova_plugin.js contain

```
{
    "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.core.file/www/FileSystem.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.core.file.FileSystem",
    "clobbers": [
        "window.FileSystem"
    ]
},
```

did you try build with >cordova build android

can you call to any other API method?

Comment: YES. the "window.FileSystem" is present in my cordova_plugins.js and NO, I haven't tried to build phonegap locally , as I am not sure how sencha touch and phoneGap merges. Also I dont have the manifest.xml in my folder. Actually the mix between sencha touch cmd and phoneGap cli  confuses me.

Comment: Hi, I managed to do it without using sencha's init phonegap technique, I just added the phonegap.js path to app.json and uploaded the production folder to build.phonegap . This works. Tell me if there are any drawbacks of not using sencha's init command.

Comment: congrats for the solution.