# how to get reference of cordova's plugins in Sencha Touch code

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, cordova-plugins

I am about to add some plugins into my cordova project.
But the cordova project is generated by Sencha Touch 2.

So if I added a plugin under cordova,

> **how to get reference of cordova's plugins in Sencha Touch code?(As Sencha Touch code is ONE level ABOVE cordova's plugin)**

And I should not touch the generated cordova code as it will be replaced every time when I re-generate cordova project by using Sencha Touch CMD commands.

---

**Update**

I'd like to clarify my question by giving a scenario :

For example, I'd like to use camera in Sencha Touch code, but getting access of the native resources in a mobile phone is done by using Cordova plugins.
And when running Sencha Touch command to generate Cordova project, all code under cordova folder will be overwritten, so cannot do the coding under cordova folder, that's why all coding must be done in Sencha Touch level.

Therefore, the problem becomes-> how can I get access to camera in sencha touch code if the plugin is under cordova's scope which means the access of cordova plugins are out of the scope of Sencha Touch.

To make it more clear, here is the structure of a Sencha Touch project which contains Cordova project:

```
Root folder for Sencha Touch Project
-app
-cordova
  -plugins
-...
```

so as you can see, plugins are under cordova folder so I don't know how to get a reference of the camera plugin like:

```
Ext.navigator.camera.function() (like this?)
```

in Sencha Touch code.

I hope my explanation makes sense to you.

Thank you.

Comment: Why no one commented on my question? Are there anything wrong with my question??? Any corrections, advice are welcome.

Comment: just rephrased my question and hopefully it conveys my expression clearly.

Comment: just added bounty to this question, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova plugins declare in their manifest (e.g. plugin.xml), using the `clobbers` element how the functionality is exposed inside the browser runtime. The `target` attribute value is the added to the window object and can be used right after `deviceready` event is fired.

More information about plugin.xml and clobbers can be found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification).

Comment: Hi Vlad, thank you for your reply. I have updated my question to clarify what I want. Please have a look and thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this [guide](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/20/SenchaPhoneGap/). The plugin is typically available as ```window.{clobberValue}```.

Comment: hi Vlad, it's great to see the official code there! However, before that code, I think there should be some steps to wire up Sencha Touch and Cordova's pulgin, otherwise we can't get reference of the camera. E.g. In order to use cordova plugins, users have to add the plugins file paths into app.js or app.json or somewhere else. So this is the part I am particularly looking for. Hope my explanation makes sense to you. thank you for your help.

Comment: The guide should be complete. There is also the problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457136/sencha-touch-with-phonegap-using-sencha-cmd-and-phonegap-build-causes-error

Comment: Hi Vlad, I reviewed your answer which is more detailed than mine, so I decided to set your post as the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at https://github.com/CaliLuke/NativeContacts/blob/master/app/view/Picture.js

For the convenience, here is the code.

```
/*
 * File: app/view/Picture.js
 *
 * This file was generated by Sencha Architect version 2.0.0.
 * http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
 *
 * This file requires use of the Sencha Touch 2.0.x library, under independent license.
 * License of Sencha Architect does not include license for Sencha Touch 2.0.x. For more
 * details see http://www.sencha.com/license or contact license@sencha.com.
 *
 * This file will be auto-generated each and everytime you save your project.
 *
 * Do NOT hand edit this file.
 */

Ext.define('Contact.view.Picture', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.contactpic',

    config: {
        height: 120,
        minHeight: 100,
        style: 'overflow: hidden',
        ui: '',
        layout: {
            align: 'center',
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        overflow: 'hidden',
        tpl: [
            '<img src="{picture}" width="160" />'
        ],
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'component',
                html: ''
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                bottom: 5,
                itemId: 'mybutton',
                right: 5,
                iconCls: 'add',
                iconMask: true
            }
        ],
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onMybuttonTap',
                event: 'tap',
                delegate: '#mybutton'
            }
        ]
    },

    onMybuttonTap: function(button, e, options) {
        Ext.device.Camera.capture({
            source: 'camera',
            destination: 'file',

            success: function(url) {
                this.fireEvent('change', this, url);
            },
            failure: function() {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'There was an error when acquiring the picture.');
            },
            scope: this
        });
    }

});
```